# On premise vs Azure SQL server performance

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a query that creates 400 transactions, each transaction running an update on a table. Running this query on the development server on premise takes around 100 ms, versus over 500 ms on Azure. I ran some statistics and RESERVED_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT came up higher than dev, with a wait count of 3523254 and 0.9 seconds wait time. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot further?

Comment: use the Session Wait Stats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 or Query Store Wait Stats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15  post the Actual Execution Plan on https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: And if it's 400 seperate transactions, each requries a physical log flush on commit.  So a 1ms difference in log write wait time per transaction could account for this.  Try wrapping all 400 changes in a single transaction.

Comment: I tried running the query in SSMS and it crashed, so I can't get the execution plan. This is part of performance testing Azure vs On Premise. Running one transaction with 400 changes runs faster in Azure than on Prem. But running 400 transactions with one change or 10 changes is slower in Azure. So I am trying to determine why and see if there is anything we can do to improve it.

Comment: Here are the stats I got by running the query in SSMS (no execution plan) https://imgur.com/a/zPE3vXy

Comment: Again: most likely CPU and memory is faster but disk latency (which you need for a transaction commit) is slower, so that perfectly explains the results you are seeing. Can you not just upgrade to faster disks?

Comment: The disks are the fastest Azure can provide. We had slower ones and upgrading them improved the times a bit, but not by much.

Comment: Is this Azure SQL Database or SQL Server on an Azure VM?  What is the storage solution for the log files in the on-prem scenario.

Comment: It's a SQL cluster on an Azure VM. The storage solution for the log files is Dell PowerVault ME4024.

Comment: Consider using SQL on azure as MS plans it - not in a VM. And get the fastest and more discs. Latency may be an issue on a VM side.

Comment: I suggest moving this question over to dba.stackexchange.com - this is a programming forum, and this is MUCH more an admin than a programming question. in dba you are WAY more likely to find admins with in depth experience on teh difference with Azure.

Comment: Are you using default transaction isolation level?